# I can’t get the second function to work on the second click of the button

Tags: javascript, html

I can’t get the second function to work.
Here is the code that I need help with:
HTML:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Store</legend>
  <p id="p"></p>
  Spaceship: $2900
  <input type="button" value="Buy" onClick="buy()" />
</fieldset>
```

JS:

```
function buy() {
    var isStart = false;
    var clickCount = 0;
    if (!isStart) {
        clickCount++;
        if (clickCount == 1) {
            var money = 10000;
            money = money - 2900;
            $("#p").text(money);
        }
        if (clickCount == 2) {
            var money = 10000;
            money = money - 2900 * 2;
            $("#p").text(money);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me!

Comment: Both `if()` statements do the same thing. What is the second click supposed to do differently?

Comment: And what's the point of `isStart`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You redeclare `clickCount` every time you execute the function and therefore reset it to false...

To maintain a "global" state for `clickCount`, you must define it *outside* the function that uses it.

```js
var clickCount = 0;
function buy() {
    var isStart = false;
    
    if  (!isStart) {
        clickCount++;
        if (clickCount == 1) {
            console.log('clickCount == 1');
            var money = 10000;
            money = money-2900;
            $("#p").text(money);
        }
        if (clickCount == 2) {
            console.log('clickCount == 2');
            var money = 10000; // Reset here, so the result is the same
            money = money-2900;
            $("#p").text(money);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Store</legend>
    <p id="p"></p>
    Spaceship: $2900
    <input type="button" value="Buy" onClick="buy()" />
</fieldset>var clickCount = 0;
function buy() {
    var isStart = false;
    
    if  (!isStart) {
        clickCount++;
        if (clickCount == 1) {
            console.log('clickCount == 1');
            var money = 10000;
            money = money-2900;
            $("#p").text(money);
        }
        if (clickCount == 2) {
            console.log('clickCount == 2');
            var money = 10000; // Reset here, so the result is the same
            money = money-2900;
            $("#p").text(money);
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that you do the same thing with the `money` variable so the final amount is always the same.

You must declare `var money = 10000;` outside the function. Inside the function you only change the amount like: `money = money-2900;`.

#### UPDATE

Here is how you would basically do it. All you need to do is keep track of the money in a global variable.

Now, on every click you will subtract the cost of the product from the remaining money.

See how many variables and checks were unnecessary ;)

```js
var money = 10000;

function buy() {
    money = money-2900;
    $("#p").text(money);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Store</legend>
    <p id="p"></p>
    Spaceship: $2900
    <input type="button" value="Buy" onClick="buy()" />
</fieldset>
```

Now, you will notice that you can still buy the product even when you don't have enough money. I leave it to you to solve that problem.

Comment: The result shouldn’t be the same, it should be money = money - 2900 * 2.

Comment: In that case you can leave `var money = 10000;` inside the function. BUT: you should really rethink your logic here. Why not make each click subtract 2900? Start with any amount of money, then every time you click "Buy", subtract 2900 from the current amount (stored in a global variable).

Answer (score 0):

your `clickCount` and `isStart` values are being set back to `0` and `false` whenever you click the button. put both values outside of the function:

```
    var isStart = false;
    var clickCount = 0;
    var money=10000;
    function buy() {
        if  (!isStart) {
            clickCount++;
            if (clickCount == 1) {
                money=money-2900;
                $("#p").text(money);
            }
            if (clickCount == 2) {
                money=money-2900;
                $("#p").text(money);
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Like @Sebastien says in the last part of his answer, you're also redeclaring `money` as well, so be sure to only declare that once, outside of the function.

Comment: See the last part of my answer